# Importing a Vue library in nuxt.js via plugins

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Any idea how I'm going to use this plugin? https://github.com/DimanVorosh/vue-json-rpc-websocket/blob/e2199d89dc15f50e57e7c5c70adfd95e5ceb5cda/src/wsMain.js

I see that it is auto registering with vue but I can't use it in nuxt.

I created the `plugins/vue-json-rpc-websocket.client.js`, registered in `nuxt.config.js` as

```
'~/plugins/vue-json-rpc-websocket.client.js'
```

but I have no idea what to write in the `inject` method and IF I have to do it to make it work. `this.$socket` is undefined in component.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import JRPCWS from 'vue-json-rpc-websocket'

Vue.use(JRPCWS, 'wss://bsc-ws-node.nariox.org:443', {
    reconnectEnabled: true,
    reconnectInterval: 5000,
    reconnectAttempts: 3
})

// do I need this?
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
    // Inject $hello(msg) in Vue, context and store.
    // inject('hello', msg => console.log(`Hello ${msg}!`))
}
```

also, any idea how can I ENV the `'wss://bsc-ws-node.nariox.org:443'` string?

Comment: For the ENV part, Have you looked at this? https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally working on my side with [the package that you're using](https://github.com/DimanVorosh/vue-json-rpc-websocket) and your given configuration. No need to inject anything so far!
Here is a fresh repo created for the example: https://github.com/kissu/so-nuxt-json-rpc-websocket

The below screenshot is using a `console.log(this.$socket)` in a `mounted` hook in `/pages/index.vue` but you can also use `$vm0` and access the instance directly from the devtools after selecting the `root` component (in the screenshot too).
[image]

---

For the env variables part, you can create an `.env` file at the root of your directory like this

```
WS_URL="wss://echo.websocket.org"
```

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    wsUrl: process.env.WS_URL,
  },
}
```

Then, use this variable in your plugin like this

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import JRPCWS from 'vue-json-rpc-websocket'

export default ({ $config: { wsUrl } }) => {
  Vue.use(JRPCWS, wsUrl, {
    reconnectEnabled: true,
    reconnectInterval: 5000,
    reconnectAttempts: 3
  })
}
```